# Timeout::Error: timeout while waiting for angular with Capybara + rails

Tags: angularjs, capybara, capybara-webkit

I have an integration test that is failing for the reason:

```
"Timeout::Error: timeout while waiting for angular"
```

I have run the test with selenium so that I can see what happens, and the page loads perfectly fine.  I threw a debugger in my test so that I can browse around the app with the test fixtures-- and everything works perfectly...

Yet in the debugger, as soon as I type "page", to query what capybara thinks it sees, I get:

```
[5] pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1>)> page
Timeout::Error: timeout while waiting for angular
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@my_app/gems/capybara-angular-0.0.4/lib/capybara/angular/waiter.rb:30:in `timeout!'
```

So basically it's lying to me because angular is fully loaded, api calls are happening and responding with json, the templates are getting interpolated...  What the... ?

Answer (score 0):

This gem has been updated to 0.1.0, which fixes the problem you are describing. Cheers!

Issue & Pull Request: https://github.com/wrozka/capybara-angular/issues/11